# edittext setOnclicklistener android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a listview , and edittext on top of it. The edittext is searching data from listview. Listview is populated from string-array. The edittext search function is working fine, but onclick is not working. It should go to another activity passing some intents. How can I do that? I am using this method.IS it correct ? How to pass the intents?

```
  editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `onClick` not working? Please elaborate.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign an onClick event that would open another activity to an EditText???  Especially since it sounds like the EditText would be used for search the ListView.  This sounds like bad UI design.

Comment: @SBerg413 what do you suggest then? An autocomplete textview in stead of edit text??

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359176/android-edittext-onclicklistener.

Answer (score 15):

If you set the android:focusableInTouchMode property of the EditText view to "false" in the layout xml file, the onClickListener should behave as expected.

Comment: It works, but `EditText` works as `TextView` (cursor doesn't appear, text is not entered).

Answer (score 2):

Say the name of your activities are `FromActivity` and `ToActivity`, then you should write something like this:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

That should load the desired activity.

**Edit:** Although you should really reconsider invoking the `Activity` on a button click maybe. Invoking it in the `onClick` of the `EditText` is not something a user would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If your onClickListener is not called, ensure that your `EditText` is actually clickable. You can do that either by a [XML configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable) or [programmatically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29).

Then, in your listener, do exactly as Aki explained in another answer of this page.