# TimePicker Dialog from clicking EditText

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I've already got a DatePicker which pops up when the user clicks on the EditText field

```
eReminderDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //To show current date in the datepicker
                Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
                mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(AddReminder.this, new OnDateSetListener() {
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                        selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1;
                        eReminderDate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Select Date");
                mDatePicker.show();
            }
        });
```

I've tried doing a TimePicker in a similar way but was unable to get it working. This is my attempt at getting it working

```
 eReminderTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddReminder.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        eReminderTime.setText( ""selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    }
                }, hour, minute);
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();

            }
        });
```

Is it impossible to do it similar to the way I did it for DatePicker?

I've tried even just making a TimePicker pop up once the EditText field is clicked with this code.

```
      eReminderTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
```

For some reason when I entered that into Android Studio the 'showDialog' was scored out.

Can anyone give me tips on where I'm going wrong? Or am I just going to have to use a Custom DialogFragment?

Comment: What doesn't actually work in your second code block?, does it just not appear, does it not compile?

Comment: Shows an error at the setText part between the "" and selectedHour, says a ',' or a ')' is needed but when I put a ',' it says "cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)"

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
eReminderTime.setText( "" + selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
```

Your missing a `+` between `""` and selected hour, `setText` methods only take a single string, so you need to concatenate all the parts (the first quotes are likely unnecessary).

```
eReminderTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddReminder.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    eReminderTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
```

That should fix your second error, you weren't providing the last parameter.
[TimePickerDialog Constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#pubctors)

Comment: Tried that and think I might of tried that before because I got this message before. Is now showing an error everything after 'new TimePickerDialog' and before 'mTimePicker.setTitle'. The error is 'Cannot resolve constructor 'TimePickerDialog(com.appname.classname, android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, int, int)' '

Comment: If you check the android documentation, you need to add a final boolean parameter stating whether the dialog is 24 hours or not.
TimePickerDialog(Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)

Comment: Completely forgot about the true/ false boolean, seen that earlier but forgot to include it when I changed my code to something similar to the date picker. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome thanks. You're probably going to want to format the minutes too:
eReminderTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + String.format("%02d", selectedMinute));

Comment: I hope it will be more useful and re-usable -> [TimePickerUniversal](https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/a1cf5a6ce8ced6fc302f95ae17bbc94f)

Comment: `eReminderTime .setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", selectedHour, selectedMinute))` produces better time representation.

Comment: How would i identify whether the user has selected AM or PM if I disable is24View?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659954/timepickerdialog-and-am-or-pm

Answer (score 28):

Why not write in a re-usable way ?

Create SetTime class:

```
class SetTime implements OnFocusChangeListener, OnTimeSetListener {   

       private EditText editText;
       private Calendar myCalendar;

       public SetTime(EditText editText, Context ctx){
           this.editText = editText;
           this.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
           this.myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

       }

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                int hour = myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                new TimePickerDialog(ctx, this, hour, minute, true).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.editText.setText( hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
        }

    }
```

Then call it from onCreate function:

```
    EditText editTextFromTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFromTime);
    SetTime fromTime = new SetTime(editTextFromTime, this);
```

Comment: How to get AM/PM?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the below code in the onclick listener of edittext

```
  TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                              int minute) {

            tv_time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
        }
    }, hour, minute, false);
     timePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

I extended the nice reusable solution of @Sumoanand to support both focus change and click listeners when changing the time multiple times. Also updating the picker calendar to remember the last selected time + formatting HH:mm

```
public class TimeSetter implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText mEditText;
    private Calendar mCalendar;
    private SimpleDateFormat mFormat;

    public TimeSetter(EditText editText){
       this.mEditText = editText;
       mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
       mEditText.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus){
            showPicker(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showPicker(view);
    }

    private void showPicker(View view) {
        if (mCalendar == null)
            mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        new TimePickerDialog(view.getContext(), this, hour, minute, true).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        if (mFormat == null)
            mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());

        this.mEditText.setText(mFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
    }

}
```

Usage from onCreate:

```
EditText timeEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
new TimeSetter(timeEditText);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution :) I have edited it to use with AM/PM. Check out here : [TimePicker with/without AM/PM](https://gist.github.com/pratikbutani/a1cf5a6ce8ced6fc302f95ae17bbc94f)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this will work for you, it works for me just fine.

Create a method for the Date/Time picker dialog.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is called, below method will be called.
    // The arguments will be working to get the Day of Week to show it in a special TextView for it.

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        String year1 = String.valueOf(selectedYear);
        String month1 = String.valueOf(selectedMonth + 1);
        String day1 = String.valueOf(selectedDay);
        delivDate.setText(month1 + "/" + day1 + "/" + year1);
        delivDay.setText(DateFormat.format("EEEE", new Date(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay - 1)).toString());
    }
};
```

and then, wherever you want you can do it just like this

```
public void setDateOnClick (View view) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener,
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    //Create a cancel button and set the title of the dialog.
    datePicker.setCancelable(false);
    datePicker.setTitle("Select the date");
    datePicker.show();
}
```

hope you find this as your solution.

Comment: I like the two lines "// Create a cancel button [...]" and "datePicker.setCancelable(false);" hue hue hue

Comment: I think this question is not related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have not put the last argument in the `TimePickerDialog`.

```
{
public TimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute,
            boolean is24HourView) {
        this(context, 0, listener, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
    }
}
```

this is the code of the `TimePickerclass`. it requires a boolean argument `is24HourView`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick1(View v) {
  DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, 2013, 2, 18);
  dialog.show();
}

public void onDateSet1(DatePicker view, int year1, int month1, int day1) {
  e1.setText(day1 + "/" + (month1+1) + "/" + year1);
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code; explain what your code is doing and why it resolves OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class **Your java Class** extends ActionBarActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{
date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
date.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        date.requestFocus();
        date.setOnClickListener(this);
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);

        setDateTimeField();

private void setDateTimeField() {
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fromDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Some additional information about this code only answer would probably be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

For me the dialogue appears more than one if I click the dpFlightDate edit text more than one time same for the timmer dialog  .
 how can I avoid this dialog to appear only once and if the user click's 2nd time the dialog must not appear again ie if dialog is on the screen ?

```
          // perform click event on edit text
            dpFlightDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                    // date picker dialog
                    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(frmFlightDetails.this,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                    dpFlightDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                                }
                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
            tpFlightTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog
                    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(frmFlightDetails.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                            tpFlightTime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
                    timePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In all of the above, the EditText still needs the `focusable="false"` attribute in the xml in order to prevent the keyboard from popping up.