# TimePicker on EditText click

Tags: android, timepicker

How to set a `Timepicker` on `EditText` Click in android.

I have searched the following links but it doesn't work as the `showDialog()` is now depricated.

[TimePicker Dialog from clicking EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901946/timepicker-dialog-from-clicking-edittext)

http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-create-time-picker-dialog-selecting-time-android

any help would be acknowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for the same:-

Include the following methods in your Fragment.

```
public void selectTimeToDisplay(EditText edText) {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DisplayTimeFragment(edText);
        dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }

public void setSelectedTime(String hourOfDay,String minute, EditText edText) {
    edText.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
}
```

Define DisplayTimeFragment as a Inner class in your Fragment:-

```
public class DisplayTimeFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
        EditText edText;
        public DisplayTimeFragment(EditText edText){
            this.edText = edText;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            String sHrs, sMins;
            if(minute<10){
                sMins = "0"+minute;
            }else{
                sMins = String.valueOf(minute);
            }
            if(hourOfDay<10){
                sHrs = "0"+hourOfDay;
            }else{
                sHrs = String.valueOf(hourOfDay);
            }
            setSelectedTime(sHrs,sMins, edText);

        }
    }
```

Now, Write the following code in the onClickListener of your Edittext.

as,

```
edStartTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectTimeToDisplay(edStartTime);
            }
        });
```

**Note:-**  For Smooth functioning, Set `focusable to false` in the `xml` of the `Edittext.`

Bingo.. It will work as charms for any no of EditText now...

Answer (score 1):

Use this method for time picker android developers site

```
    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

and to call it you can do it like this

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/pick_time" 
android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog" />
```

showTimePickerDialog method

```
    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Comment: It seems your ans can help me a lot. will check and if fine will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `TimePickerDialog` class to display it as Dialog. Here is sample code:

```
  TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                }
            }, 0, 0, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();
```

This code you may call in your `OnClickListener` method