# How to popup a TimePicker on click of text box in Andriod 2.3.3?

Tags: android

I am new in Android development and i need a text box to focus on or clicked on, the Time picker should popup in a text box. please help me in this regard. i did a lots of google search and could not find a proper solution for that.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText pops up TimePicker for Alarm/Reminder System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841404/edittext-pops-up-timepicker-for-alarm-reminder-system)

Comment: before posting my question i tried this but not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following and you will get a nice time picker for your text box:

```
final EditText my_Time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_time);

    my_Time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(TimeActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                   my_Time.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
```

In your xml create an edit text

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_time"
            android:text="20:00"
            android:editable="false" 
            android:focusable="false"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestApp extends Activity {

private TimePicker timePicker1;
private Button btnPopUp;
private int hour;
private int minute;

static final int TIME_ID = 999;
```

Now, In your On Create method call for a button click.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(Test.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();

}
```

Now, on button click event

public void addListenerOnButton() {

```
    btnPopUp = (Button) findViewById(Test.id.btnPopUp);

    btnPopUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(TIME_ID);

        }

    });

}
```

Finally, on your create dialog method write below code.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_ID:

        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                                    timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);

    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

        timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
        timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

    }
};

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
       return String.valueOf(c);
    else
       return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is tested with android2.3.3. Please go ahead and check android with android