# android: display a toast message after clicking on edittext

Tags: android-edittext, message, toast, clickable

I don't know if this is possible but I am looking for a way to display a toast message after clicking on edittext.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
        editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(RectangleWidth.this, "message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841609/5666415

Answer (score 1):

First you should set the edit text to `android:focusable="false"` in your xml code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution from a UI point of view. See here: [Android EditText onClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359176/android-edittext-onclicklistener)