# Previous EditText value clears as requested but does not allow for new user input

Tags: android-fragments, android-edittext, user-input

I am working on a fragment that holds a seek bar, the seek bar value is updated in the editText element if used .  User can also  update seekbar by typing in the value on the editText.(this all works, until i implemented the clearing of the previous value)

the seekbar is  defaulted to 500 (midpoint) and the textView shows 500.  As the seekbar progress changes, the value in the editText matches it. (this kind of works)

When the user inputs a new value by selecting the EditText element I wanted the 500 (or what ever value) to disappear for the new input.  (this works).

The problem is: every time I enter a new value on the softkeyboard and select the tick,the new value just clears, the softkeyboard still stays up and the progress bar or the edittext is not updated.  What have done wrong?

**SEEKBAR - Updating EditText**

```
private int radius = 500;
//START SEEKBAR DISTANCE
distControl=(SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.sb_loc_dist_set);
txtInMaxMiles=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_max_num_input);
distControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()

{
    int progressChange = 0;

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar,int progress, boolean fromUser){
    radius = progress;
    txtInMaxMiles.setText(String.valueOf(radius));
}
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
    distControl.setProgress(radius);
}
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch (SeekBar seekBar){
    txtInMaxMiles.setText(String.valueOf(radius));
}});//END: SEEK BAR DISTANCE
```

**Edit Text - updating progress bar**

```
 txtInMaxMiles.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String txtIn;

        @Override //Before screen fully loads
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
           // txtIn = txtInMaxMiles.getText().toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            txtIn = txtInMaxMiles.getText().toString();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            txtIn = txtInMaxMiles.getText().toString();
            if (txtIn == null || txtIn.trim().equals("")) {
                radius = 0;
            }
            if (radius < 1 || radius > 1000) {
                txtInMaxMiles.setError("Please input a number between 0 and 1001");
            } else {
                txtInMaxMiles.setError(null);
                distControl.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
               // txtInMaxMiles.setText(Integer.toString(radius));
            }
        }
    });
```

**On Click EditText element**

```
  txtInMaxMiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtInMaxMiles.setText("");
            }
        });
        return view;
```

I think this is a quickfix, but im just missing something so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Managed to work it out.This time i didn't hardcode the radius (naughty), made the code cleaner.  However even after doing this....OnClickStill didnt work.  So i tried another approach where the text is highlighted and replaced as the user inputs the new value in, this thread was useful: [Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus)
However, I still tried onClick...and it didnt work, even though it was a step closer.
In the end Lukas Batteau saved the day on this thread [Android EditText onClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359176/android-edittext-onclicklistener)
And instead of using onClick I changed to OnTouchListener.

```
 txtInMaxMiles.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        txtInMaxMiles.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            int txtIn;

            @Override //Before screen fully loads
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                txtInMaxMiles.clearFocus();
                txtInMaxMiles.requestFocus();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                txtIn = Integer.parseInt(txtInMaxMiles.getText().toString());

                if (txtInMaxMiles.getText().toString() == null || txtInMaxMiles.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                }
                if (txtIn < 1 || txtIn > 1000) {
                    txtInMaxMiles.setError("Please input a number between 0 and 1001");
                } else {

                    txtInMaxMiles.setError(null);
                    distControl.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                }
            }
        });

        txtInMaxMiles.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
                    txtInMaxMiles.clearFocus();
                    txtInMaxMiles.requestFocus();
                }
                return false; // return is important...
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Ok, so I am still very much a novice, so any clear up coding advice will be appreciated, and if anyone knows the reason how onClickListener did not work please let me know, as i have no clue why.